# Change screenshots in meta data of app in itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to change the screenshot of app published in itunes without creating new version of it? 
When i log in to itunes and see my app meta data, I am not able to find edit option for screenshots.

- I am new to mobile app as the current app was done by another developer.
- Mine is web app not native mobile app.
- If I create new version does it make users to log in again?
- Should i upload the build again for the project?
  I would like to know the impact of creating a new version like how long does it take to see the new screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change screenshots of a live app, you need to create a new version. (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)

Officially web apps are not allowed on the store. Make sure your new version adheres to the store rules, specifically 4.2.
(https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)

If you replace an existing (native) app with a new web app, I'm 100% sure that users need to log in again.

Yes, you need to create a new version / build and upload it to iTunes Connect. Then you can upload new screenshots as well. After that, you can send the app to review, which usually takes 1-2 days.